# How do I use TypeScript and jest.requireActual() (with named exports)?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have a simple file called `functions.ts` which contains:

```
export const log = console.log.bind(console);
```

And a jest Mock for it in `__mocks__/functions.ts`, borrowed from [the Jest requireActual() documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename):

```
const originalModule = jest.requireActual("./functions");

// Quiet functions.log() during tests
export default {
  __esModule: true, // Use it when dealing with esModules
  ...originalModule,
  log: jest.fn(),
};
```

I wish to make the `log()` function useless, ie for the function to not do anything (people used to call this a no-op).

```
import { runMe } from "./stackoverflow";

jest.mock("./src/backend/functions");

test(`pass, but make sure it doesn't log error messages`, () => {
  runMe();
  expect(true).toBeTruthy();
});
```

And the actual function being ran:

```
import { log } from "./src/backend/functions";

export const runMe = () => {
  console.log(`log is:`, log);
  log(`Hello`);
};
```

The

```
console.log(`log is:`, log);
```

returns `log is: undefined`.

Everything works perfectly (but still logs) if I remove the `jest.mock("./src/backend/functions");` though.

**How do I use TypeScript and jest.requireActual()?** Ie so the tests for `runMe()` will be quiet when I run them (but also so the other functions in `functions` still work as normal)?

Comment: Your test double needs the same interface as the thing it's replacing - the minimal `__mocks__/functions.ts` is `export const log = jest.fn();` (i.e. a _named_ export, not a _default_ export).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did think about that - but how can I provide all the other functions in `functions.ts` in the mock - ie, the `jest.requireActual()`?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use `jest.requireActual` with types, just pass the type of your import as a parameter.

Something like this should work:

```
import { log } from './functions';

jest.mock('./functions', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual<typeof import('./functions')>('./functions'),
    log: jest.fn(),
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to export every named export manually, to ensure `log()` was mocked but everything else in `functions` worked.

In `__mocks__/functions.ts`:

```
const actualFunctions = jest.requireActual("../functions");

// Mock this
export const log = jest.fn();

// Use actual implementation of everything else
export const sleep = actualFunctions.sleep;
export const stringify = actualFunctions.stringify;
export const hexToUtf8 = actualFunctions.hexToUtf8;
export const instructionDataToNote = actualFunctions.instructionDataToNote;
```

It won't update automatically like using deconstruction would have, but it seems like this is the only way.